# Python3 - Pulling values out of a request

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a script to get some data from a website via requests.

Below is the response I get when I run the code:

```
<input name="ht" type="hidden" value="2ae4a75e1a965da01fa7c54f29a9f8a8275876f9:MTUxMDE2ODQ5Mi40MDk0"/>
```

My desired repose is to pull out the two below strings for use later on in the script:

```
2ae4a75e1a965da01fa7c54f29a9f8a8275876f9

MTUxMDE2ODQ5Mi40MDk0
```

If it is any help these two stings above are always the same length.

I have tried print(ht)[:x] but it throws an error every time.

CODE:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('http://18montrose.us11.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=6b0a46846ebdd9e62be420915&id=d63240a5fe')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")
ht = soup.find("input", {"name":"ht"})
print(ht)
```

Comment: Have you tried asking BeautifulSoup for the attribute value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to cast to a `string` and then do this.

```
a = str(ht)

val = a[a.index("value")+6:len(a)-3] # getting the substring from 'value=' to end

print(val.split(':')[0]) # split on : and get 1st and 2nd part

print(val.split(':')[1])
```